# How to convert ico to png in memory ?

Tags: node.js, png, imagemagick, converters, ico

I'm doing ico converter to png online. Example : user key in http://www.google.com.my/favicon.ico. I will able to convert .ico into png and send back the image. I'm using nodejs as server to convert it. 
How to do the convert at nodejs ?

Answer (score 1):

There is an Imagemagick module you may find useful:
https://github.com/rsms/node-imagemagick

Comment: I had done it with physical file convert. The problem is how can i deal with in memory convert without through the physical file read write ?

Comment: it looks like resize can take a binary data as it's srcData parameter and supports callback function for which it returns a similar binary format as it's second paramter, as per the 'Example with stdin/stdout:' example on the https://github.com/rsms/node-imagemagick page.